# Function not working when event is called

Tags: javascript, function

Trying to make a container's visibility change upon click.  The visibility is set
to hidden in CSS and the form is within a div.  Any help appreciated.  I have also
tried using the *display* property and setting it to *none* or *compact* instead of the *visibility* but still no change.

### JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayCont()
    {
    var idName= this.value;
    var getElmt= document.getElementById("idName").style.visibility;
    if (getElmt == hidden) 
        {
        getElmt = visible;
            }
    else if (getElmt == visible)
        {
        getElmt = hidden;
        }
    }
</script>
```

### HTML Excerpt

```
<form id="btns">
    <input type="button" value="Timer" id="timerBtn" onclick="displayCont()"/>
    <input type="button" value="Countdown" id="ctDownBtn" onclick="displayCont()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things wrong. First off, idName is undefined. Also, when you're using getELementById('idName'), remove the quotes to use the variable you just defined. Also, you need quotes around visible and hidden. Im working on the code right now.

This should be closer to what you're looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
          #myDiv{
            display: none;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="btns">
        <input type="button" value="Timer" id="timerBtn" onclick="displayCont('myDiv')"/>
        <div id="myDiv"> Show/Hide This </div>
    </form> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayCont(inp){
            var ele = document.getElementById(inp);
            var shown = ele.style.display;
            if (shown == 'none') {
                ele.style.display = 'block'
            }
            else {
                ele.style.display = 'none'
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added the quotations but still no change.

Comment: @user3280654 The code above shows the basic example of toggling between hidden and shown. You'll have to take that idea and implement it with what you have.

Comment: I'm starting to understand, but what is the variable inp inside the function parameter?

Comment: In this case inp is equal to 'myDiv' because that's what we passed into the function inside out <input> tag. So basically whatever id you want to toggle just pass it into the displayCont function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that getElmt is just a string, not a reference.

Here is what you want:

```
function toggle(id){
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Then you can toggle your element with

```
toggle('idName');
```

Comment: I personally use jquery because most things you want to do like this have already been implemented in jquery.